# Django Comments Signals firing twice

Tags: django, comments, django-signals, django-1.5, django-comments

I've attached a handler to the django.contrib.comments signals (comment_was_posted and comment_will_be_posted). Each handler is being called twice. I can't seem to figure out why, nor can I figure out how to tell if I'm on the first or second call. I only want to run the code once. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Signals firing twice is usually the result of the registration code firing twice.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals